# Where can I get a comprehensive list of GMLAN Symptom category codes?

Tags: obd-ii, gm

> GM and several other manufacturers have added additional information to the 5 digit codes.  These are not “codes” but are “Symptom categories”.  The DTC symptom is made up of an additional 2 digit code that is place after the 5 digit code (usually a space between the two codes)  The first digit following the DTC indicates the symptom category, while the second digit refers to the subsystem or a more in depth information about the symptom. There are 16 possible symptom categories available for 0 to 9 and A to F.  Currently there are only 8 categories in use, 0 through 7

My question is where can I get a comprehensive list of these symptom categories and subsystems?

Internet is not of much use to me!

I can find Symptom categories 0 to 7 online.

8 to F are reserved for future use. Have these been allocated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outside of paid service information like ProDemand or AllData, I think you'll have very little luck finding this information. Here's a sample from a 2012 Impala. The list is too long to post the whole thing, but you can infer the meaning of some of the symptom codes from it.

> U0073 71   ECU HS Bus Off
>   U0073 72    ECU LS Bus Off
>   U0100 00    Lost Communication with Engine/Powertrain Control Module (ECM/PCM)
>   U0100 75    Lost Communication with Engine/Powertrain Control Module (ECM)
>   U0100 7F    Lost Communication with Engine/Powertrain Control Module (ECM)
>   U0101 00    Lost Communication with Transmission Control Module (TCM)
>   U0101 75    Lost Communication with Transmission Control Module (TCM)
>   U0104 00    Lost Communication with Cruise Control Module
>   U0104 7F    Lost Communication with Cruise Control Module
>   U0151 00    Lost Communication with Inflatable Restraint Sensing and Diagnostic Module (SDM)
>   U0151 71    Lost Communication with Inflatable Restraint Sensing and Diagnostic Module (SDM) Invalid Serial Data Received
>   U0151 7F    Lost Communication with Restraints Control Inflatable Restraint Sensing and Diagnostic Module (SDM) Erratic
>   U0401 00    Invalid Data Received From ECM
>   U0401 72    Invalid Data Received From ECM Message Counter Incorrect
>   U0401 74    Invalid Data Received From ECM Bus Signal Checksum Error
>   U0402 72    Invalid Data Received From Transmission Control Module Message Counter Incorrect
>   U0402 73    Invalid Data Received From Transmission Control Module Parity Error
>   U0402 74    Invalid Data Received From Transmission Control Module Bus Signal Checksum Error
>   U0405 71    Invalid Data Received From Cruise Control Module Invalid Data
>   U0405 72    Invalid Data Received From Cruise Control Module Message Counter Incorrect
>   U0405 74    Invalid Data Received From Cruise Control Module Bus Signal Checksum Error
>   U0415 00    Invalid Data Received From Electronic Brake Control Module
>   U0415 72    Invalid Data Received From Electronic Brake Control Module Message Counter Incorrect
>   U0415 74    Invalid Data Received From Electronic Brake Control Module Bus Signal Checksum Error
>   U0416 00    Invalid Data Received From Vehicle Dynamics Control Module
>   U0416 72    Invalid Data Received From Vehicle Dynamics Control Module Message Counter Incorrect
>   U0416 74    Invalid Data Received From Vehicle Dynamics Control Module Bus Signal Checksum Error

Comment: Thanks so much. Am cool with the 5 digit DTCs, apparently I have to subscribe to data sources such as you listed to access the extra 2 digit codes

Comment: Thanks for adding the info, Ben. Over the top as usual :o)